# Vue how to handle object with arrays that needed to editable

Tags: vue.js

I am working on project with vue.js and element.ui and I am not sure how to handle a problem.

I have an array of objects like this that includes arrays in them, for example:

```
array: 
[
 {
   "name": string
   "array1": array
 }
]
```

I have a table with v-for to display this array of objects like this:

```
<tr v-for="(man, index) in array" :key="index">
  <td>
     <el-input v-model="man.name"></el-input>
  </td>
  <td>
     <el-input v-model="man.array1"></el-input>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I try to edit the main array1 the type is changing to string but I am not sure which way is the best to change it back to array.

How do you recommend to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

`el-input`is not made to handle arrays.
an html input deals with text (or numbers) only.
You can't display an array in an input so ... it can't give you back an array.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve so I can't help you more but you can edit your question to give us more informations.